# Wrong results on multiple inner joins with an OR condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, left-join, inner-join

I have three models: `Event`, `Comment` and `Photo`. An Event has both `has_many :comments` and `has_many :photos`.

My goal is to find all Events which have received new comments and/or photos in the last 24 hours.

Assume that two events exist, one with a recent comment and another with a recent photo.

If I query them separately with a single join, everything works as expected:

```rb
Event.joins(:comments).where("comments.created_at >= :today", :today => Time.now.beginning_of_day)
```

returns: `[#<Event id: 1>]`

```rb
Event.joins(:photos).where("photos.created_at >= :today", :today => Time.now.beginning_of_day)
```

returns: `[#<Event id: 2>]`

Why is it when I combine both joins:

```rb
Event.joins(:comments, :photos)
    .where("comments.created_at >= :today OR photos.created_at >= :today", :today => Time.now.beginning_of_day)
```

that I receive `[#<Event id: 2>, #<Event id: 2>]` — twice #2, but not #1?

The SQL generated by ARel is

```sql
SELECT "events".*
FROM   "events"
       INNER JOIN "comments"
               ON "comments"."event_id" = "events"."id"
       INNER JOIN "photos"
               ON "photos"."event_id" = "events"."id"
WHERE  ( comments.created_at >= '2013-03-25 23:00:00.000000'
          OR photos.created_at >= '2013-03-25 23:00:00.000000' )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an SQL problem : you have to specify LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.  `include` will do it for you :

```
Event.include(:comments, :photos).where(...).uniq
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your suggestion, but adding `.uniq` only returns Event #2 once, instead of Events #1 and #2?

Comment: sorry I misunderstood.  As MurifoX say, you have to do left join and not inner join.  try Event.include(:comments, :photos).where(...) I will correct my proposition if it's the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is because of the `INNER JOIN`. This query would bring ONLY the `events` that has both `photos` and `comments` associated with it.
You can try using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER` on your RDBMS and see that both results are fetched.

Comment: Thank you, `LEFT JOIN` works indeed better. Still, I am not entirely certain about the explanation. If two `INNER JOIN` only result in rows matching BOTH `photos` and `comments`, why do the single-JOIN queries return only one each? In that case, the query with two JOINs should yield zero results, not #2 twice.

Comment: Maybe the #2 have a photo and a comment?

Comment: No - that's the part that baffles me. If I join on `comments`, I get Event #1. If I join on `photos`, I get Event #2. If I join on both, I get Event #2, Event #2.

Comment: Oh, i get it now. The problem is the `OR`. There are two records that matches this condition, but the join excludes one and duplicate the result. In your case i believe it is better to use `AND`, as if you want the two conditions to be met.

Comment: Thanks again for your continued help. Wouldn't that only find Events that have BOTH matching comments and photos? This is what it looks like to me — using `AND` results in zero matches.

Comment: Yeah, that's odd. There is no way i could setup a db here to give it a test, but, have you tried using `INNER` and `AND` on your query?